# What is this tiny lizard?

Tags: species-identification, herpetology

This tiny guy stumbled into our house in the suburbs of Sydney. What species is it?

It's dark and has two yellow stripes going along the length of its body. They start on its head and go right above its eyes.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a Common Garden Skink (*Lampropholis guichenoti*)

[Further information can be found here](http://tenrandomfacts.com/common-garden-skink/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_garden_skink)

The description is a quote from the first source:

> The colour of the skin of a common garden skink is mostly a brown-grey colour, and it usually has a black or dark coloured stripe down either side of its body and a copper coloured head. The diet of common garden skinks generally consists of insects and vegetation, and can include caterpillars, spiders, slugs, cockroaches, crickets, worms and ants, and fruit and vegetables. Small and enclosed spaces, such as rocks or trees, are the sought after home for common garden skinks, and they are commonly found in urban gardens, hiding in among plants or leaves. Common garden skinks generally grow to a length of 9 centimetres (3.5 inches), and they have five toes on each of their four legs, as well as a long tail. Common garden skinks can release their tails when caught by predators, such as birds, cats and larger reptiles like snakes.